# how to alter a mysql table to add a column which contains a common value for all rows by checking another columns repeating value

Tags: mysql, insert, compare, alter

how to alter a mysql table to add a column which contains a common value for all rows by  checking another columns repeating value.

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| id | inode    | name         |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 | 12059010 | IwnsuAaJUFaa |
|  2 | 12059015 | IwnsuAaJUFab |
|  3 | 12059016 | IwnsuAaJUFac |
|  4 | 12059017 | IwnsuAaJUFad |
|  5 | 12059018 | IwnsuAaJUFae |
|  6 | 12059019 | IwnsuAaJUFaf |
|  7 | 12059020 | IwnsuAaJUFag |
|  8 | 12059021 | IwnsuAaJUFah |
|  9 | 12059022 | IwnsuAaJUFai |
| 10 | 12059023 | IwnsuAaJUFaj |
| 11 | 12059013 | iPhZIWtZdSaa |
| 12 | 12059015 | iPhZIWtZdSab |
| 13 | 12059016 | iPhZIWtZdSac |
| 14 | 12059017 | iPhZIWtZdSad |
| 15 | 12059018 | iPhZIWtZdSae |
| 16 | 12059019 | iPhZIWtZdSaf |
| 17 | 12059020 | iPhZIWtZdSag |
| 18 | 12059021 | iPhZIWtZdSah |
| 19 | 12059022 | iPhZIWtZdSai |
| 20 | 12059023 | iPhZIWtZdSaj |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

i need a fourth column having a common number for all rows group by same "inode" number.

Comment: I do not understand "checking another columns repeating value" and 'common number for all rows group by same "inode" number'.  Can you clarify or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the column using something like

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD [columname] [columntype]
   ```
2. Change the content of that column using `UPDATE`.